# how to write text starting from the end of the textBox in C# ?

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox, reverse

I am writing a chat application in C#, and I would like also to display the time of the arrival of the message, just after the message, starting from the right?
How can I write in a textBox or a richTextBox starting from the right?

This is how my code looks for now:

```
        textBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
        textBox1.AppendText(text + "\n");
        textBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Italic);
        textBox1.AppendText("sent at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm") + "\n");
```

Comment: Are you asking how to right align half of the text?

Comment: Is this using Windows Forms or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [TextBox.TextAlignment Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textalignment(VS.95).aspx)

```
textbox1.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
```

Otherwise, if it is a fixed size and there are no line breaks, you could do something like this

```
string time = "12:34PM";
string text = "Hello".PadRight(100) + time;
textBox1.AppendText(text + "\n");
```

or using your existing code... maybe something like this?

```
textBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
textBox1.AppendText(text + "\n");
textBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Italic);
textBox1.AppendText(("sent at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm")).PadLeft(100) + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks :) 
It worked with the alignment property :

```
        textBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
        textBox1.AppendText(text + "\n");
        textBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Italic);
        textBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        textBox1.AppendText("sent at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm") + "\n");
        textBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appendtext, I would suggest string.format

```
string text = "This is the message \n";
string dt = "sent at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm") + "\n"
textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", text, dt);
```

You could also append the string after using a length function of the main text, and adding the date after.